# Entity Framework 1 to 1 / 1 to *

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this setup of classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPasswordId { get; set; }
    public virtual ArchivedPassword CurrentPassword {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ArchivedPassword> UsedPasswords { get; set; }
}
public class ArchivedPassword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
ModelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedPassword>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Users)
    .WithRequired(e => e.CurrentPassword)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CurrentPasswordId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

ModelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.UsedPasswords)
    .WithRequired(e => e.User)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When i try to add a user and a password, ef can´t figure out the update order.
Is this a mapping Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on Database .But i think you can not make two different Foreign Keys for same tables.But you can success what you want as below code

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Password> Paswords { get; set; }

}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Password Password
    {
        get
        {
            return Passwords.ElementAt(Passwords.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
}

public class Password
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```